# How to optimise a Production Build with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm building a small static site for a client with webpack as my build tool, and I'm a bit lost on how to optimise and set up Webpack for a production build since tutorials are mostly from 1.x and I've recently upgraded to 3.6 as I've never done this before.

I just got Stephen Griders Webpack 2 course from Udemy but wondering if anyone could shed some extra light and tips/recommendations on what plugins and tools I will need to add/do in my webpack.config and package.json?

Thanks

```
// webpack.js
var path = require('path');
var autoprexir = require('autoprefixer');

var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
entry: './src/js/index.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/bundle.js', 
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: 'babel-loader'
         },
        {
            test: /\.css$|\.scss$/,
            use: extractPlugin.extract({  
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: [
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 2, sourceMap: true }},
                    { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, plugins: () => [autoprefixir] }},
                    { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true }},
                ],
            }) 
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: ['html-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 4000,
                        name: 'img/[name].[ext]',
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'css/main.css',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ 
        template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])
]
};
```

-- package.json

```
{
    "name": "Template",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
      "build:prod": "webpack -p"
     },
    "browserslist": [
      "> 1%",
      "ie > 9"
    ],
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
      ....
      "webpack": "^3.6.0",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {} 
}
```

-- .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 7"]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: what is the question? any errors?

Comment: How do I optimise for a production build is the question, I'll edit this to make it a little more specific, but I'm not sure what plugins I'll need and setup to do so, always just set it up for a dev environment @AmrAly

Comment: If you don't get any errors what you need is to run `npm run build`  this will generate all your code in production version which will be minified and then you can serve it as static file.

Comment: @AmrAly I haven't configured a production build properly I'm just using a default one, that is why I am asking. 
I haven't done any minifying, optimisation or anything else hence why I am asking for help with good plugins to use or tips... I have set up a development webpack build only.
Saying use 'run npm build' doesn't help (especially when i have build & build:prod)